# How to choose most performant renderer, Canvas or WebGL

Tags: javascript, canvas, webgl, pixi.js

I'm developing a game with [PIXI.js](http://www.pixijs.com/) for desktop devices. PIXI has both WebGL and Canvas renderers available, we will use WebGL wherever it's supported by the device.

My problem is that some low end devices technically *support* WebGL, although it does not run well, due to having a slow GPU. In some cases Canvas rendering would perform much better.

***How Can I decide at runtime which renderer to use?***

Perhaps the WebGL context contains some useful information.

Comment: The (native) WebGL context does not have any performance information on it, however measuring the frametime in your gameloop should do the trick easily.

Comment: Have you considered just asking the user like most PC games do?

Comment: @gman Good suggestion, but our users will probably not have a clue what the message is talking about. They're not the most technical bunch.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Official approach is to use `failIfMajorPerformanceCaveat` flag on context creation. Here's link to the spec explaining how it should work:
https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/specs/latest/1.0/#5.2.1

It is supported for a while on Chrome (since 2013 I think), so chance are it may rule out very well a few "slow" implementations.

Bad news is that as of the time of writing PixiJS, it seems, still cannot pass arbitrary parameters to WebGL context creation. I haven't rechecked, but issue on that is officially not closed yet:
https://github.com/pixijs/pixi.js/issues/1738

So you'll have to hijack the PixiJS code or create web context manually.

Also, of course, not every browser supports this relatively new flag.

If stability is more important than performance, one additional option is to disable WebGL completely for native Android browser before 4.4, where Chrome Web View is officially introduced. This will rule out older custom WebGL implementations (e.g. Sony xperia one).

Personally I am reluctant to make stress test in the beginning of the app to choose rendering implementation. Small glitch/spike in performance may cause switch to canvas on perfectly good hardware. But if you want to go this route, there's a discussion on implementing it in PIXI here:
http://www.html5gamedevs.com/topic/1733-detect-performance-issues-to-display-a-message/